# Lookup a nested variable in YAML with Ansible

Tags: ansible

After reading docs and finding some related Q&A here I can't see how this information applies to my case.

Namely, consider this YAML file referenced as variables file in my playbook:

```
---
prod:
  gitlab_accounts:
    reader_all:
      username: foo
      password: bar
```

Then, I can retrieve this structure in a debug task:

```
- name: test
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{prod}}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [IP] => {
    "msg": {
        "prod": {
            "gitlab_accounts": {
                "reader_all": {
                    "password": "bar",
                    "username": "foo"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question: how can I reference just single variables from this structure? I tried different approaches but neither syntax, also in examples works.

I use Ubuntu 20 with Python 3.8.10 and according to console output, Ansible core 2.11.6 (Ansible is however install via python-pip and has package version 4.9.0)

*UPDATE*

Approach: use for example, `prod.gitlab_accounts.reader_all.username`

Error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option 
with an undefined variable. 
The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'gitlab_accounts'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a variable `prod` with that content, you can get at a single value (like the password) by writing something like `prod.gitlab_accounts.reader_all.password`. So:

```
- name: test
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: 
      - "username: {{prod.gitlab_accounts.reader_all.username}}"
      - "password: {{prod.gitlab_accounts.reader_all.password}}"
```

Assuming you have a file `prod.yaml` containing the example content in your question, the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - prod.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: test
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg:
          - "username: {{prod.gitlab_accounts.reader_all.username}}"
          - "password: {{prod.gitlab_accounts.reader_all.password}}"
```

Produces as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [test] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "username: foo",
        "password: bar"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Note that it should also work just fine using an `include_vars` task. This playbook behaves identically:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: config.yml
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "type 1: {{hosttype1}}"
          - "type 2: {{hosttype2}}"
```

Comment: thx - for some reason, with your approach I get an error message that gitlab_accounts is not under prod (?)

Comment: If you're getting an error either you data doesn't look like you've described it or you have a typo in your playbook. I've updated the answer with a complete example.

Comment: thank you! indeed my failure has been obviously to use include_vars; with vars_files as in your example it works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: It should work the same using `include_vars`; I've updated the answer with an example.